# Creating unblockable Pop Up on click

Tags: popup, infobox

how can i create a popup which isn't blocked when a user clicks on a specific text? So if someone want more to know about something the person can just click the text an get a pop up like on following website.

http://www.berater-mainz.de/cms/struktur.html

Is there a simple way? Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: Do not use the js alert function. Use a hidden div, that you can show when a button is clicked.

<div style='display:none;'><!--INFO--!></div><script>$(function(){
$('button').on('click', function(){
$('div').css('display', 'block');});})</script>

Presuming that your are using JQuery. The same is easily possible with javascript.

Comment: Until now i just used CSS and HTML no JavsScript or so on ^^. I also don't want a button just a Text like a link.

Comment: I do not think that's possible. Would you object to using JavaScript?

Comment: Sure, it was just an information that I'm not familiar with JavaScript until now ^^

Comment: Here's how to include JQuery to the page.
`<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write([
        "\<script src='",
        ("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://",
        "ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'>\<\/script>" 
    ].join(''));
</script>`

Comment: Ok to make it clearer I don't have any idea what you are doing with this code. It would be fine if you could give me a little working example so I can understand what happens.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show a complete example. Is this something that you could be looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the JavaScript alert function as this can be blocked by browsers. 
Instead use a hidden div that you can show when a button is clicked.

First you will have to include the JQuery library in your HTML File by including a link to it in the head. A library is basically a lot of code written for you so that you can invoke complicated functions with less code.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    document.write([ "\<script src='", ("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://", "ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'>\<\/script>" ].join('')); 
   </script> <!-- This script tag includes JQuery's functions in you page. -->
</head>

<div style='display:none;'><!--This is the popup box!--></div> 
<script>
$(function(){ 
    $('button').on('click', function(){ //When the button is clicked...
        $('div').css('display', 'block'); //Show the previously hidden div
    });
});
</script>
```

... as far as I know, there is no way to do it without JavaScript.